# Problem while using bs4: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape a Goodreads Page to get all editions of a book, but when I run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/xxx/PycharmProjects/wikipedia_pageview/isbn.py", line 141, in <module>
    ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn) 
  File "C:/xxx/PycharmProjects/wikipedia_pageview/isbn.py", line 79, in get_editions_details
    if ed_link := f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}":...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried to put conditions for this reason in the selected areas but they don't work.
Code:

```
def get_editions_details(isbn):
# Create the search URL with the ISBN of the book
data = {'q': isbn}
book_url = get_page("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
#print(book_url)
# Parse the markup with Beautiful Soup
soup = bs(book_url.text, 'lxml')
# Retrieve from the book's page the link for other editions
# and the total number of editions
if ed_item := soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink"):
    if ed_item := ed_item.find("a"):
        print(ed_item)
    else:
        pass

if ed_item:
    ed_num = ed_item.text.strip().split(' ')[-1].strip('()')

if ed_link := f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}":#capire...
    print(ed_link)
else:
    pass
return((ed_link, int(ed_num), isbn))  



if __name__ == "__main__":
        try:
            os.mkdir('./urls_files')
        except Exception:
            pass


    isbns = get_isbn()

    for isbn in isbns:
            ed_details = get_editions_details(isbn) 
            get_editions_urls(ed_details)
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code that error line is. I see no `if ed_link := ...` in what you've posted.

Comment: Right... see my edit. I posted another part of the code it wasn't really necessary

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/why-do-i-get-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

The indentation in your example seems to be not correct and will not handle wrong or missing isbn or editionlinks.

#### How to fix?

Assign the values to `ed_link` and `ed_num` in the moment you can be sure there exist a `href` in `ed_item` else set them to `None` or `0` or handle these issue in another way:

```
def get_editions_details(isbn):

    data = {'q': isbn}
    book_url = requests.get("https://www.goodreads.com/search", data)
    soup = bs(book_url.text, 'lxml')

    ed_link = None
    ed_num = 0

    if ed_item := soup.find("div", class_="otherEditionsLink"):
        if ed_item := ed_item.find("a"):
            ed_link = f"https://www.goodreads.com{ed_item['href']}"
            ed_num = ed_item.text.strip().split(' ')[-1].strip('()')
        else:
            pass

    return((ed_link, int(ed_num), isbn))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #just as example to simulate an error
    ed_details = get_editions_details(1)
    if ed_details[0]:
        get_editions_urls(ed_details)
    else:
        print(f'no editionlinks for isbn:{ed_details[2]}')
```

Comment: I have an error with that: requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'None': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://None?

Comment: As mentioned, you have to handle the case, that there are no results - Take a look, added a check that will skip execution of `get_editions_urls(ed_details)`

Comment: thanks!!! it kinda works after adjusting